# Break a "when" on a class type argument into several functions

Tags: kotlin, jvm

Let's consider the following function :

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> dispatch() = when (T::class) {
    String::class -> println("I'm a String")
    Float::class -> println("I'm a Float")
    else -> println("I'm something else")
}
```

Is there a way to break it into several other functions, using a polymorphic dispatch instead of a "when" structure, doing something in this spirit ?:

```kotlin
fun dispatch<Float>() = println("I'm a Float")
fun dispatch<String>() = println("I'm a String")
```

Furthermore, what is the performance cost of such "when" statement ? Let's say I call `dispatch<String>()` : the "when" can be resolved at compile time. Will a clever compiler see that and just replace it with `println("I'm a String")`, or will there be a performance overhead ?

Comment: This has the feel of an X-Y question. What are you trying to achieve with this? There may well be a different approach that wouldn't need this sort of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Well that's the problem down to its core. I need a function that have different behaviors for some specific types, and a default behavior for all others, and a way to split that behavior across multiple functions/classes/interfaces instead of a single big function. I'm also genuinely interested in the answer to these questions.

Comment: The usual object-oriented approach is to have a method implementing the default behaviour in your superclass, and then override it as needed in subclasses. Obviously you can't do that with the system classes, which raises the question of whether it would be better to wrap them or similar  but it's hard to advise without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the possibility to call `dispatch` with some reified type parameter from another inline function, you could replace the `when` block with extensions of the different class's companion objects:

```
fun String.Companion.dispatch() = println("I'm a String")
fun Float.Companion.dispatch() = println("I'm a Float")
```

Then it's not `dispatch<String>()` but `String.dispatch()`, and you got rid of the `when`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to break it into several other functions, using a polymorphic dispatch instead of a "when" structure, doing something in this spirit ?:

No.  There's no way to do that for this function.

There are occasionally ways to do similar things, but you generally at least need a `T` or  `Foo<T>` to make that work.